# Select highest value for the key in dictionary that is highest among the keys lower than given "at" value

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

Is there a better way of writing this, with LINQ instead of custom method.
Sorted Dictionary is not an option.
I think that Dictionary.Where(x => x.Key < at) is fine but
.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Last() will be slow, as I need only one value I am wasting 
CPU for ordering.

```
Dictionary.Where(x => x.Key < at).OrderBy(x => x.Key).Last().Value;
```

maybe:

```
Dictionary[Dictionary.Where(x => x.Key < at).Max(x => x.Key)];
```

Comment: The second one looks best too me, only minor tweak you could make there is to use the keys collection: `Dictionary[Dictionary.Keys.Where(k => k < at).Max()];`

Comment: With a binary search tree backend this could be achieved in O(log n) instead of O(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option is good. It first finds the max Key and then the Value that goes with it.
Alternatively, you could write a MaxBy method.
Or just use the one already implemented in MoreLinq:
http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary[Dictionary.Keys.Where(key=> key < at).Max()]
```

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The OP's one doesn't use `.Keys` so it's not the same at all.

Comment: This is a very good approach because accessing `Dictionary.Keys` is an O(1) operation (i.e. very efficient) and then `.Where()` and `.Max()` are both O(N) operations. I think it would be hard to find any better approach.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I know, that's why I commented as *almost similar* rather than *exactly same*. but still for me it makes no difference, no performance benefits nothing. Just another way of writing OP's second version.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Aye, true it probably makes a negligible difference.